# condition_variable term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, threadpool, mutex

I'm having an issue using wait with my condition_variable and a function. I want my main to **wait** until my pool thread has finished all of it's tasks before continuing on with the program. I thought to use `std::condition_variable` and an `isFinished()` pool function to make main wait. Here's what I did:

```
//above are tasks being queued in the thread pool
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mainMut);
    waitMain.wait(lock, pool.isFinished());
}
//I need to make sure the threads are done with calculations before moving on
```

and my `pool.isFinished()`

```
//definition in ThreadPool class
bool isFinished();

//implementation
bool ThreadPool::isFinished()
{
    {//aquire lock
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex>
            lock(queue_mutex);
        if(tasks.empty())
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }//free lock
}
```

but I just get the error

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\condition_variable(66): error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments
1>          main.cpp(243) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::condition_variable::wait<bool>(std::unique_lock<_Mutex> &,_Predicate)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Mutex=std::mutex,
1>              _Predicate=bool
1>          ]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pool.isFinished()` is evaluated and returns a `bool`, but `condition_variable::wait` expects a functor that it can call repeatedly to determine when to stop waiting. You could do this with `std::bind`:

```
waitMain.wait(lock, std::bind(&ThreadPool::isFinished, &pool));
```

or a lambda:

```
waitMain.wait(lock, [&]{ return pool.isFinished(); });
```